# using a dynamic vector as an index value in for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, dynamic, vector

```
a=1:5
for k=a
    if k<3
        a=[a k+5];
    end
disp(k)
end
```

When I run this code, I get these results:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

k uses only the initial vector when it enters to the loop. I want it to update the values of a and take the new values of a too.
Thus, my question is how do I get this result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: you can try: for k=1:length(a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=1:5
i=1
while i<=length(a)
    k=a(i);
    if k<3
        a=[a k+5];
    end
    disp(k)
    i = i + 1
end
```

should do the trick. (Disclaimer: I didn't test it)

The index `i` iterates over `a` until it is *really* over.

Comment: When I test you code it enters an infinite loop with k = 1

Comment: thanks for help! and we should put an i=i+1; to the bottom of disp(k) to make it avoid infinite loop

Comment: @BarsGunduz and Benoit_11 Of course! Just added it.

Answer (score 2):

```
ints = 1:5;

i = 0;

while i ~= length(ints)   

   i = i + 1;

   if (i < 3)
      ints = [ints i + 5]
   end

   disp(i)

end
```

Comment: @glglgl just forgot to increment i